# i want to get information from db which must be a login persons details

Tags: php

I need to get groupID from groups table which is must be a login person's groupID.this is the code i wrote for that.(model)

```
 public function getgroupID()
     {
         $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
         $query = $this->db->query("select groupID from groups where member01ID=".$username);
         return $query->result();
     }
```

Comment: You have to bind your variables - don't just paste them in the middle of your SQL query. I don't know what DB class you're using, but it will be in their documentation if you search for "[dbClass] query bind".

Comment: `$username` that stands to be a string, *n'est-ce pas true?* If so, that needs to be quoted.

Comment: Ok..... and what's the question?

Comment: @h2ooooooo: This looks like CodeIgniter.  They have an "active record" (read: query builder) class: http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html

Comment: @RocketHazmat It seems you're right. The record builder seems to have very standard methods, [but `session->userdata` gave it away](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html).

Comment: $query = $this->db->query("select groupID from groups where member01ID='$username'");
this also i used but that also ot worked

Comment: Check for errors then. CI has its own method https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/errors.html

Comment: $data['id'] = $this->mod_group_profile->getgroupID(); i used this in controller and view i used this code <?php foreach ($id as $row) {
                             echo "<option value='" . $row->groupID . "' >" . $row->groupID . " </option>";
                         }
                         ?>

Comment: when i run my code no errors are showed the correct url is called and nothing displayed.